# How to set location enabled in SFMCSdkModuleConfig

Tags: marketing-cloud, android, sfdcmobilesdk-android

I want to set localization as enabled when initializing the `SFMCSdkModuleConfig`. So, I am looking for the equivalent to `setLocationEnabled` in the iOS SDK: https://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/MarketingCloudSDK-iOS/appledocs/MarketingCloudSdk/8.0/Classes/MarketingCloudSDKConfigBuilder.html#/c:objc(cs)MarketingCloudSDKConfigBuilder(im)sfmc_setLocationEnabled:

Could you tell me how to setup it on Android?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Please see the documentation pages for Geofence Messaging:

iOS Doc: https://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/MarketingCloudSDK-iOS/location/geolocation-overview.html

Android Doc: https://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/MarketingCloudSDK-Android/location/geolocation.html